# OpenId connect Spring security 5 and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to implement an authorization server Google like. After a few hour spend searching I'm not able to find the solution. 
Where can I find a simple example to do that?
I'm trying to use the `@EnableAuthorizationServer` annotation but I don't know it it is the right way.

Comment: Provide some code what you are trying.

Comment: Did you find any solution to implement OpenId connect with Spring security 5. If yes, can you please share the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I switched to oauth2 implementation

Answer (score 0):

OpenID is now supported by Spring Security 5.
This is a good place to start:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-openid